# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET wampserver cant load js on localhost

Tags: javascript, apache, localhost

When I start wampserver(apache php mysql) and access the url `http://localhost/index.html`, I find the website can't load jquery.js or any other big js files. (Not only chrome but also other browsers)

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='./jquery.js'> </script>
```

And the console echo **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**. Besides I can get the js files from CDN.

But I create a js file and input some words, I can get it  through localhost.

Several weeks ago, it worked correctly. And I check the error.log. There is nothing error. And access.log it's Ok 200, which means the file was accessed successfully.

I guess the question is firewall. Because I clicked the btn of resetting the firewall several ago. But I dont know if that's the problem and how to resolve it.

I don't use https or nginx reverse proxy.

[image]

Comment: If you don't know what the problem with your firewall might be: How should we know? (we don't even know _which_ firewall you're running, nor its configuration or the defaults). You have a file named vue.js or jquery.js in the same directory as that index.html, right? Because that's what your browser would attempt to load it from. Note: The file size in the access log that you post looks suspiciously like 2^16 bytes - I rarely see files with exactly that size, which might give you some hint on where in your environment to search further